# How can I fall back to a high contrast color in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some XAML which sets the foreground color directly:

```xml
<Style x:Key="HomeHeaderText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Light UI" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF606060" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,50,0,30" />
</Style>
```

I would like to detect in the style whether or not the system is in high contrast mode, and fall back to one of the system colors if so.

How can one do this using styles?

---

I tried setting this using a trigger, but this results in `XamlParseException` at runtime:

```xml
<Style x:Key="HomeHeaderText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Light UI" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF606060" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,50,0,30" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Foreground"
               Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that `DataTrigger.Binding` wants a binding, but you gave it a direct value. You can solve this by setting the binding source:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}
```

However, this will not be dynamic -- the style would not update if someone toggles high-contrast while the application is running. Ideally it would be nice to have something like this:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters}, Path=HighContrast}
```

But unfortunately that isn't possible since it's a static property. So, binding to the `HighContrastKey` resource is the better option. Instead of using `Tag`, you could bind this to an attached property. Come to think of it, Microsoft probably should have implemented `SystemParameters` as attached properties in the first place. Try something like this:

```
public static class SystemParameterProperties {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighContrastProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighContrast", typeof(bool), typeof(SystemParameterProperties),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() {Inherits = true});

    public static bool GetHighContrast(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HighContrastProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHighContrast(DependencyObject obj, bool value) {
        obj.SetValue(HighContrastProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I used `Inherits = true` on the property so that we can just set it on the outermost container and let it be accessible everywhere, i.e.:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:attachedProperties="..."
        attachedProperties:SystemParameterProperties.HighContrast="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Static Member=SystemParameters.HighContrastKey}}">
    ...
</Window>
```

Finally, your trigger would be:

```
<Trigger Property="attachedProperties:SystemParameterProperties.HighContrast" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: This is really nice -- and allows changing the value for a subset of the UI at runtime if one needs to do that for some reason. Have some rep :)

Comment: OK, I lost. Personally, I would have preferred the version of mine, because it's less verbose in the XAML.

Comment: @MarioVernari I wish there was a better way (or is there?) to initialize a global attached property than putting it at the top of every window. But once it's set, I think the usage is more elegant than binding to a static "Instance" property. On the other hand, your singleton could actually wrap the entire SystemParameters class automatically, if you use INotifyPropertyChanged and [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) (overriding TryGetMember) instead of dependency properties.

Comment: "Elegance" is something subjective! However, I prefer to avoid exposing "invitations" to hard-events (i.e. INotifyPropertyChanged) when the class is static or singleton. That may lead to memory leak when the host forgets to subscribe the event weakly. A DP can't lead to any issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have solved leveraging an helper:

```cs
public class HighContrastHelper
    : DependencyObject
{
    #region Singleton pattern

    private HighContrastHelper()
    {
        SystemParameters.StaticPropertyChanged += SystemParameters_StaticPropertyChanged;
    }

    private static HighContrastHelper _instance;

    public static HighContrastHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new HighContrastHelper();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void SystemParameters_StaticPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
        if (e.PropertyName == "HighContrast")
        {
            HighContrastHelper.Instance.IsHighContrast = SystemParameters.HighContrast;
        }
    }

    #region DP IsHighContrast

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHighContrastProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsHighContrast",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(HighContrastHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            false
            ));

    public bool IsHighContrast
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsHighContrastProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(IsHighContrastProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion  
 }
```

Afterward, the usage in your code is straightforward:

```
<Style x:Key="HomeHeaderText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Light UI" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF606060" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,50,0,30" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighContrast, Source={x:Static local:HighContrastHelper.Instance}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did the same thing and then realized that all that was needed as to change the binding to Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrast}}" as per comment by sa_ddam213.

Comment: Binding directly to SystemParameters.HighContrast doesn't work because the value is not updated when the user changes the setting; it gets set once at app startup that way.

Comment: Actually, wait a sec, when High Contrast is turned on after the app, this works, however, it does not seem to have the right value at startup if High Contrast is already on.

Comment: This can be fixed in the initializer when the _instance is created. That is, add _instance.IsHighContrast = SystemParameters.HighContrast after the "new". Also, this seems to require .NET 4.5

Comment: It's a been I don't bump against this class, but I believe you're right. Once in the office, I'll try that. About .Net 4.5: although I use only 4.5, why do you say that's mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it to Tag property of textblock and use that in DataTrigger like below:

```
  <Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
     <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HighContrastKey}}"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag , RelativeSource= {x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```